# netty basic udp server with bytebuf error SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf toString

Tags: java, sockets, netty, bytebuffer, datagram

I am trying to set up a basic netty UDP server using the latest netty (4.1.5). All I want to be able to do as the moment is receive a packet and display the contents in the console.

I have 2 classes as follows;

```
public final class UdpServer {

    private static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "6565"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                    .handler(new UdpServerHandler());

            b.bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

the handler class is as follows;

```
public class UdpServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

    static ByteBuf buf;

    @Override
    public void channelRead0 (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
        System.err.println ("Messaged received on " + new Date() + ":\r");

        buf = packet.content();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
        buf.readBytes(bytes);
        buf.retain();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.err.println (buf.toString());
        buf.release();
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

now, whenever I send a packet across in bytes which the contains the word heelo, I always receive the following message

```
Messaged received on Sun Sep 04 23:35:05 BST 2016:
SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 5, widx: 5, cap: 2048))
```

I presume the ridx and widx refers to the 5 characters of hello?

Could anyone please review my code or shed further light on this please?  Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you seeing any exceptions/errors?

Comment: `ridx` is the read index, the index of the next place to read into. `widx` is the write index, the index of the next place to write into. You read 'hello'`, which occupies the first 5 bytes, so byte index 5 is the next place to read into. And write into. `cap` is the capacity provided when constructing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the content as string use `buf.toString(Charset)`

Comment: Hi Norman, I am sorry to annoy with with a simple reques. I have tried the following to, sadly to no avail.     <pre> System.err.println (buf.toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));<code> When I used this, I received a blank message. Could you please help? many thanks